# change displayimage of buttons on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a few buttons:

```
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/1.jpg"><img src="images/button.png"></button>
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/2.jpg"><img src="images/button.png"></button>
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/3.jpg"><img src="images/button.png"></button>
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/4.jpg"><img src="images/button.png"></button>
```

if one of them is pressed i want to change the img like a selected and unselected button.

```
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/4.jpg"><img src="images/button_selected.png"></button>
```

my thought was to do a click function, but i have lots of buttons on the page (over 25) and i dont think 25 clickfunctions for appending different images is the right way.
any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: what about using live function of jquery for future events?

Comment: Do the buttons click to another page or stay on the current page with something else happening?

Comment: they were used for a click function to change the background image of the current viewed div. and i want to change the img inside the button too

`$(".image1-button").click(function() { 
    var url = 'url(' + $(this).data('image') + ')';`this is what the button does

Answer (score 3):

You don't need 25 click events:

```
$(".image1-button").click(function(){
   $(".image1-button img").attr("src", "images/button.png")
   $(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/button_selected.png");
});
```

Comment: yeah dude, that works great! exactly what i wanted, but how can i say that all the others get "button.png" back
i press one nad the other get their old img back...

Comment: @TedMosby I've edited my answer. When a button is clicked all images are reset to `button.png`. Then **this** button's image is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use toggle function to switch between two images like this[enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/),

```
$('.image1-button').click(function(){

   $(this).find('img').toggle('src', $(this).data('image'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(.image1-button).click(function(){
$(this).children('img').attr("src","images/button_selected.png");


})
```